# JS regex with \x escape sequence not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function that should replace both `?paging={something}` and `&paging={something}` from the URL.

The below regex works everywhere but not in Firefox, what's wrong?

```
function myPagination(){
    var url = window.location.href.replace(/\?paging=(.+?)\x/, "");
    console.log(url);
    url = url.replace(/\&paging=(.+?)\x/, "");
    console.log(url);
    return url + addPaging();
}
```

Comment: What is `\x`???

Comment: Interestingly enough `/\x/` is not an error in FF. It does not seem to match anything. In Chrome it matches a literal `"x"`, which it shouldn't I guess.

Comment: @Kay it should match a "x" in Firefox as well. How do I do this?

Comment: Just use `x` instead of `\x` to match character "x" literally.

Comment: @Anonymous Remove preceding slash

Comment: @Anonymous, why did you think that you needed to escape the `x`? With that information maybe we can add an answer that will help later readers, too.

Comment: @Kay to be honest I am not an expert with Regex, so probably I just made a mistake

Comment: \x delimits hexadecimal character escape sequence: eg /\x0A/.test('\n') // true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly a human error as `\x` is an unknown escape sequence without the hex digits following it.

Have a look at [Mathias Bynens' *JavaScript character escape sequences* reference](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes):

> Characters without special meaning can be escaped as well (e.g. `'\a' == 'a'`), but this is of course not needed. However, **using `\u` outside of a Unicode escape sequence, or `\x` outside of a [hexadecimal escape](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal) is [disallowed by the specification](http://es5.github.io/x7.html#x7.8.4)**, and *causes some engines to throw a syntax error*.

The [specification](http://es5.github.io/x7.html#x7.8.4) only mentions:

> *HexEscapeSequence ::*
>   x *HexDigit HexDigit*

Thus, if you planned to match `x`, just use `x` without the `\` in front of it.

**The rule of thumb when writing regex**: *Never use ambiguous patterns*!

Comment: Interestingly, /\x/ in Firefox does not even throw syntax error, it just does not match anything.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the behavior for this is not defined, each implementation can handle unknown escape sequences differently. That is why it is important to write unambiguous patterns, escape what must be escaped only.